# Listening for HTMX events with Alpine.js in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, alpine.js, htmx

Django templates can [listen for events from HTMX](https://htmx.org/docs/#event_naming) via listeners added to the Javascript part of code. In this case I want to change DOM element(s) after an update on the page.

Below works fine:

```
document.body.addEventListener('htmx:afterSwap', (() => {
    // get input element, clear its value
}))
```

I'm using Alpine.js which helps handling dynamic parts on the client side. I want to connect it to HTMX events since it apparently [picks up custom events](https://alpinejs.dev/essentials/events#dispatching-custom-events).

Unfortunately, when trying to subscribe to any HTMX event, e.g. `htmx:after-swap` in

```
<form x-on:htmx:after-swap="console.log('event received')"
    hx-post="{% url 'my_url' %}"
    hx-target="#responses"
>
```

I have no output in the console.

Do I need to first trigger Alpine's 'custom event' from plain Javascript (e.g. in the working `addEventListener` block above) or can I connect HTMX with Alpine.js directly?

I have tried:

- various cases combinations (I gather kebab is the way for Alpine.js);
- tried various HTMX events such as `htmx:load`;
- replaced `x-on` with `@`;
- found HTMX+Alpine.js examples elsewhere (for instance involving `x-data` prefix) but none of them worked for me.

I would like to understand the process, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alpine will not be able to listen to the event unless it's dispatched directly to the element where you added the listener, or a child element. In this particular case, adding the [`window`](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/on#window) modifier will most likely work.

```
<form x-on:htmx:after-swap.window="console.log('event received')"
    hx-post="{% url 'my_url' %}"
    hx-target="#responses"
>
```